# Error message when I save my video with OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm having an error when I run my code, I don't understand what is happening but I think is when the program finish because I have the result what I want, that is convert an existing video to gray scale and save it.

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/output.avi')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('results/output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))

while (cap.isOpened()):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    out.write(frame)

    # Key events
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:  # esc
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There may be a case where at least one of the frames in your video weren't read in properly.  That's why the `cv2.cvtColor` method is throwing an error because the frame data you are providing is empty.

You should consider using the first output of `cv2.VideoCapture.read()` to make sure the video frame was properly captured, then write it to file.  The first output is a flag that determines if the current frame was read in successfully.  Also, you'll need to handle the end where we reach the end of the video.  In that case, the flag will be `False` so that we should exit the loop.  Finally, if it's your intent to write grayscale frames, there is an optional fifth parameter in `cv2.VideoWriter` called `isColor` where we can set this to `False` to allow us to directly write grayscale frames.  This means the call to `cv2.cvtColor` is no longer required.

One additional thing I'll recommend is to infer the frame width and height from the video file instead of setting it yourself.  This way the input and output resolution is the same.  Finally, don't forget to release the `cv2.VideoWriter` object when you're finished and I've added an additional check for the video file to see if it has properly opened:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/output.avi')

# Check to see if the video has properly opened
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("File could not be opened")
    sys.exit(1)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))  # Get the frame width and height
frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)) 

# Change
out = cv2.VideoWriter('results/output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (frame_width, frame_height), isColor=False)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read() # New

    if not ret: # New
        break # Get out if we don't read a frame successfully

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    out.write(frame)

    # Key events
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:  # esc
        break

cap.release()
out.release() # New
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As a minor note, you don't have any windows being displayed, so `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` is superfluous here.  Consider removing it from your code.

Comment: I've gotta downvote this, because `cap.isOpened()` will keep returning `true` even after you read the last frame from the video file. What will happen once you reach the end  is that `ret` will become `failse` and `frame` will be `None`.... forever. Due to the `if not ret: continue` bit, your script will become stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @DanMašek Yeah that's what happens when I don't test my code.

Comment: @DanMašek I think I fixed it.  Please verify one more time for me.

Comment: Yeah, that looks reasonable. I'd add a single test of `cap.isOpened` before the `while` loop, to check that the input file was correctly opened. The last 3 lines are unnecessary here, but it doesn't hurt. Maybe add import statements for numpy and cv2 to make it complete. Finally, I'd probably add verification of the shape of input frames, since if it doesn't match to the 640x480 specified when opening `VideoWriter`, I seem to end up with just a 5kB video that can't be played back.

Comment: @DanMašek Great advice. I'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. One more I just realized -- there's an optional 5th parameter in the constructor of [`VideoWriter`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#ac3478f6257454209fa99249cc03a5c59) named `isColor` that's set to `True` by default. If you set this to `False` you can directly write 1 channel frames, thus avoiding the second call to `cvtColor`, and get the same result.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks for all of your suggestions.  I've changed the post.

Comment: You're welcome and got my +1 there already. I just took the liberty to get rid of couple of magic numbers there, replacing them by named constants.

Comment: @DanMašek Ah yes.  Thanks for the additional edits!

Answer (score -1):

So this answer has another approach(Here,you can also extract different color by changing the corresponding weights in front of the B,G, R values)

[image]

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/output.avi')
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))  # finds the frame width automatically
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))  # finds the frame height automatically

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('results/outpy.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, (frame_width, frame_height))

while (cap.isOpened()): # value is true if the file is successfully opened.
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:  # checks if the return value is True or False. False means file ended.
        # grey = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # the grey matrix has a different shape than the frame matrix
        # that's why the output files were blank
        # to circumvent this RGB2GRAY, I manually added the "NORMALIZED" R,G,B values.

        frame[:,:,0] = 0.114*frame[:,:,0]+0.587*frame[:,:,1]+0.299*frame[:,:,2] #multiplying normalized co-efficients to B,G,R
# for extracting red, make 0.299 as 1.0 and others as 0.0; same goes for other colours.
        frame[:, :, 1]=frame[:,:,0] # making the G and R values same as the B.
        frame[:, :, 2]=frame[:,:,0]
        # now frame is a 3d grayscale matrix. Identical to the cv2.cvtColor method....except it is 3d
        # now frame is grey scaled...R,G,B values for each pixel,holds the same number....
        out.write(frame)
    else:
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Mr. rayryeng 's code was creating blank avi files so I fixed it. I have tested my code with avi videos. it works...yay!

Comment: This can't work, since you messed up the indentation of the `while` loop body when adding the code sample. Please, fix it.

Comment: @DanMašek Yeah I deleted my answer.  It's what happens when you're on a mobile phone and you don't thoroughly test the code.

Comment: Unfortunately your attempt to "to circumvent this RGB2GRAY" is really bad -- the original conversion to grayscale is not a simple average of the 3 channels (it's weighted, see the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html)). Hence your output will be different than intended.

Comment: @DebajyotiMajumder You should really use `cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)` after the conversion to grayscale.  Your workaround won't produce the correct results.

Comment: @rayryeng, I was still having problem with saving the frame using the   `cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` . @DanMašek I went ahead and corrected the normalized weights. you can print my grayscale frame as well as the cvt color, side by side to check, it will give same 256 shades of grey!!
@DanMašek, indentation of the while loop is fine.I checked!

Comment: @rayryeng I was missing the `iscolor=false!` ,`cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)` now works. Thanks.